# Angular4/5 : Download from URL

Tags: angular

Can you please help me with this topic?  At this moment I haven't found any tutorials/posts with a reusable and understandable example.

I would like to download a remote PDF with Angular5x.

If you could show me the way to do it or suggest me some components or tutorials, I would really appreciate.

Thanks,
Andrea

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: If i ask it's because I haven't found anything about it ....a small example could be really useful for me and for all developers that have not found the solution regardings this topic.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out the [file-saver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver) package. I've never personally used it, but another team in my company uses it in their Angular application to facilitate PDF downloads.